# How do I strip off nil or empty elements from the end of my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null

Using Ruby 2.4.  I have an arry with a numbegr of string elements.  I would like to strip off elemetns that are either nil or empty from teh end of the array so I have

```
row_data.pop until row_data.last || row_data.empty?
```

But this is only stripping the nil elements off the end of the array. How do I adjust the above so that it also includes thte empty elements?

Comment: Are nil's present throughout the array or only on the end?

Comment: Hi, nils could be anywhere in the array.

Comment: If you're using Rails, `blank?` is a method that checks for nil or empty, and even works on nil.

Comment: `while row_data.last.to_s.empty?; row_data.pop end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```ruby
row_data = [ "", "hi", "", nil ]                                                 # => ["", "hi", "", nil]
row_data.pop while !row_data.empty? && (!row_data.last || row_data.last.empty?)  # => nil
row_data                                                                         # => ["", "hi"]
```

Very similar to your solution but instead we flip from while to unless cause instead of looking for the PRESENCE of an object we are looking for `nil` explicitly.  Then we check if that string is empty.  You could check if the last element has the method `empty?` if you expect other object types to be present in your array.  (But I assume you are parsing CSV so it's most likely a moot point)

If you have active_support or are inside of rails this gets easier.

```ruby
# Ignore the require if in a rails project
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'  # => true

row_data = [ "", "hi", "", nil ]                             # => ["", "hi", "", nil]
row_data.pop while !row_data.empty? && row_data.last.blank?  # => nil
row_data                                                     # => ["", "hi"]
```

**Below would remove nil or empty string from ANY position of an array**

```ruby
 row_data = [ "hi", "", nil ]
 row_data.compact.reject(&:empty?) # => ["hi"]
```

Given an array of strings, and assuming no `active_support` this will remove any nil value `compact` and then reject any string that is empty `reject(&:empty?)`  This does create a new array, and does not make any changes in place. If you need to mutate the original object use the following code

```
 row_data = [ "hi", "", nil ]
 row_data.compact!.reject!(&:empty?) # => ["hi"]
 row_data # => ["hi"]
```

If you have active support this could be reduced to

```
 row_data = [ "hi", "", nil ]
 row_data.reject(&:blank?) # => ["hi"]
```

Comment: Hi, Neither of these work.  If the array is  [ "", "hi", "", nil ], botht he first and second suggestions produce ["hi"].  I don't want to strip out nil/empty elements from teh beginning, only the end of the array.

Comment: @Natalia Ah "end" of the array, missed that.

Comment: @Natalia solution amended.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much!  Not to nit-pick but I noticed if the array is empty, ([]), your solution seems to result in an infinite loop of some kind.

Comment: @Natalia Fixed, it would try to pop for ever :) before we do anything check to see the array has things to pop.

Answer (score 1):

If the array contains only strings and `nil`s, one could write:

```
row_data = ["cat", nil, '', nil]

row_data.tap { |rd| pop while rd.last.to_s.empty? }
  #=> ["cat"]
```

Note `nil.to_s #=> ''`.

If `array` may contain other objects as well, one may write:

```
row_data = ['', 1, :cat, {}, [], nil]

row_data.tap { |rd| rd.pop while (rd.last.nil? || 
  (row_data.last.respond_to?(:empty?) && row_data.last.empty?)) }
   #=> ["", 1, :cat]
```